Replace jack stud
We are doing a kitchen renovation and we removed the small pantry. The contractor discovered that the beam is supported by a jack stud that was inside the pantry wall (see pictures)  This is now a problem because this is where the ovens are going to be, so we need to get rid of this mess of jack studs.  The contractor is thinking about adding braces because the ovens don’t go all the way up to the ceiling.  Are there any other options?




Is this a 2-story or 1-story house?

Get an opinion from an engineer.

@Machavity it’s a 1 story house.

Can the ovens be moved over a few inches so the jacks can remain?  Then no engineering needs to be done.  Plenty of times on remodels, tweeks need to be done because of instances just like this.

Looks to me like the jack studs need to be replaced anyway, unless you plan to either keep a hump in the floor there, or raise your finished floor.  The jack studs look to be sitting on top of that bottom plate, plus a couple extra pieces of lumber.  You'll need to temporarily support that beam somehow.  Do you know what's below the subfloor?

@RMDman no, it’s right in the middle. They can’t be moved

@Huesmann they will be replaced. I’m just looking for alternatives that support the beam better. I don’t know what’s below the subfloor but we have a crawl space
